# When using the Networked A-Frame (NAF) component how do I disable LERPing?

Tags: aframe

By default the [Networked A-Frame component](https://github.com/networked-aframe/networked-aframe) for [A-Frame](http://aframe.io) uses LERPing to smooth the animation between position and rotation updates for objects synced through the networked component. I'd like to disable that feature but the docs show a syntax example of `NAF.options.useLerp` which isn't an attribute that I can set on the `networked-scene` component which instead looks like this:

```
<a-scene networked-scene="
  room: handcontrollers;
  debug: true;
">
```

Where do I put the `NAF.options.useLerp` command to disable LERPing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code goes in a JavaScript tag anywhere in your page source after you import `networked-aframe`.

Simplified example that worked for me inside of `<head>` tag:

```
<script>window.NAF || document.write('<script src="https://unpkg.com/networked-aframe/dist/networked-aframe.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
<script>NAF.options.useLerp = false;</script>
```